# Using dash character in main source file name

Tags: d

I tried to compile a file `hello-world.d` with llvm D compiler and got this message:

```
Error: module hello-world has non-identifier characters in filename,
use module declaration instead
```

I looked the documentation for what is a module declaration, and then added

```
module hello_world;
```

to the top of my file. Then the hello-world file compiled. Please explain why is that needed, what module name I am supposed to use if my main file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - if you do not give the module a name, the D compiler will use the file-name (without extension) as module-name.

So, if you name your D source file `hello-world.d`, and it does not have something like `module hello_world;` at the top of the source-file, the compiler will actually try to insert and compile `module hello-world;` and that will fail because `hello-world` is not a valid identifier.

If the file name was `hworld.d` for an example, then the compiler will actually compile a module with auto-generated name `hworld`.

Answer (score 2):

In D identifiers must be comprised of only alphabetic, numeric or underscore characters. A module name is also an identifier include the packages in it.

For the latin character set alphabetic characters are a-z and A-Z. Other character sets used by languages not latin based will also work (utf-8 support).

Nothing really special going on, but keep in mind that a module (include packages) need to match the file system names for lookup purposes (e.g. imports).

Comment: They don't have to match if you pass all the files to dmd at once.